# How to use custom NavigationBar in ios TabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uitabcontroller

I'm using a TabController which has a Navigation Controller as it's root and all works fine thus far except i would like to show the NavigationBar of the child viewcontrollers within the tab bar but for now just the tabcontroller's Navigation Bar shows.

This is how the tab bar shows now. with It's NavBar

[image: This is the TabBar's header]

This is the Navbar of the child ViewController I want to show

[image: This is the Navbar of the child ViewController which i want to show]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed a `UINavigationController` for each tab bar item rather than a `UIViewController`. You can then make the root view controller of each `UINavigationController` point to the view controller you want to use for that tab.

[image]

This allows each tab to have its own navigation bar and navigation stack.

**EDIT**

Also, if you intend on keeping your current navigation controller as the initial view controller, make sure you hide it's navigation bar by unselecting "Shows Navigation Bar" in interface builder

[image]

or by setting it in `UITabBarController`:

```
self.navigationController?navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

or by setting it in `UINavigationController`:

```
self.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

Comment: I did but now both the Tab controllers navigation bar and the view controllers navigation bar is showing same times

Comment: You need to remove the navigation controller the contains the tab bar controller. Or if that navigation controller is also required, you can set it's navigation bar to hidden.

Comment: So it works now but Large title property  for the navBar isn't working. I tried enabling it both by code and on storyboard but it just isn't showing.

Comment: Works now. Had to set the property in the individual Navigationcontroller's Navigation bar. Thanks man